# SQLiteAssetHelper does not work in any way

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am actually very new to Android and trying around. Right now I want to write an app that includes a pre-filled database so I googled about four hours trying to find a solution to my problem and although I found out that SQLiteAssetHelper is useful for this, somehow it seems like that class does not copy the data from my original assets database... I'm frustrated because I'm doing this as I said for four hours continuously: What I understood was that I have to do the following to load the database file:

```
public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}
```

I followed all the instructions on the website of SQLiteAssetHelper: My asset database has the .db extension, it obviously has data in it and it is in a folder called "databases" in the assets folder.

But it always says: No such table, regardless of what I try to do. (That's why I came to the conclusion that the data might not get copied)

Kenta1561

Comment: Does your database have the table in question? Have you cleared your app's data in Settings, or fully uninstalled and reinstalled it? Remember that `SQLiteAssetHelper` only copies a database from assets *if there is not already a database there*. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsAssets-AndroidStudio) demonstrates the use of `SQLiteAssetHelper`.

Comment: Or do like me: manually copy the database if not yet existing from the `assets` folder into the `/data/data/...` folder. Well, the usual data path.

Comment: Show the exact value of `DATABASE_NAME`, the version number you have set in the pre-filled database file, and the code of the entire function that creates the `DatabaseManager`.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I just tried that again with only Log.i() statements to check if there is ANYTHING in my database and it came out that there is actually data in my system database. It might be a problem with my ListView, so I'll check it again.